# Facebook Event.subscribe comments.create not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working for me?

Example page here

http://totalcommunitycollegemove.com/post-438.html

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   
    FB.init({appId: '194189377275548', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});

};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

function catchCommentAdd()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxCommentCount.php",
        data: "id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&direction=up",
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return true;
}

function catchCommentDelete()
{     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxCommentCount.php",
        data: "id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&direction=down",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    return true;
}

FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create', function(response) { 
    alert(response);
    catchCommentAdd();
});
```

Comment: Try removing the `alert()` also try removing the like and the Fan-box to the right just to check...

Comment: I found out thanks to the dude below that the event doesnt fire unless you have the href attribute defined with the url of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the same problem but maybe found a solution (works on my test-site). It seems that the event name "comments.create" is wrong. The correct (or at least working) event is "comment.create" (without the s)

Here is my code-snippet:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId:  'APP_ID',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml:  true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
            alert(response.commentID);
        });         

    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<fb:comments href="YOUR_URL" num_posts="5" width="500" ></fb:comments>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did try this as their blog post mentions comment.create whilst the Event notification docs state comments.create. Sadly the change makes no difference here. I've posted on Facebook's dev forums and will update here if there are any responses.

Comment: after i remove the href attribute, this also no longer works. Can you try it on your page with a given href-value?

Comment: That fixed this for me. Adding the Href attribute allowed the callback to work correctly

Comment: I accepted this answer. For future reference.. You need the href attribute defined with the page the box is on.. and i used the comment.create event name.

Answer (score 2):

Use "comment.create" and not "comments.create" it's singular.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create',
function(response) { 
    alert(response);
    catchCommentAdd(); });
```

Relies on Facebook's Javascript SDK having already loaded in.  Because that happens asynchronously, you should place the code in your window.fbAsyncInit function, following the FB.init call:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   
    FB.init({appId: '194189377275548', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});

    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create', function(response) { 
        alert(response);
        catchCommentAdd();
     });
};
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat here... FB.Event.sub comments.create is not being triggered by Facewbook's new Comments plugin. The previous 'comments.add' used to work, but this has now been replace by comments.create and comments.remove.

My FV.Event.subscribe is called right after the FB.init in window.fbAsyncInit.. still no worky.... investigating today and will reply when I find an answer

Answer (score 0):

You read Facebook's documentation? That's a big mistake unfortunately.
Try with comments.add instead of comments.create...